# Computing the Jacobian of vectorized ODEs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode

This works fine:

```
syms a b x
jacobian ([a*x - a*b, a*b],[a, b])
```

but this:

```
syms a b(i) x
i = 1:6
jacobian ([a*x - a*b(i), a*b(i)],[a, b(i)])
```

returns the error:

```
Error using sym/jacobian (line 37)
The second argument must be a vector of variables.
```

In my opinion the second argument *is* a vector of variables so I don't understand the error.

Is it possible to differentiate with respect to a vector of ODEs e.g. `b(i)`? How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `syms b(i)` creates a symbolic function `b` of `i`.
So, if a vector of `doubles` is passed to `b(i)`, the output will be a vector of function values:

```
>> syms b(i)
>> b(1:6)
ans =
[ b(1), b(2), b(3), b(4), b(5), b(6)]

>> b(i) = i^2;  % Defining the actual function will generate actual values
>> b(1:6)
ans =
[ 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
```

So the error is correct: you have a list of values.
To create a vector of variables, use the `sym` function

```
>> b = sym('b',[1,6])
b =
[ b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6]
```